# RESTful API hosting on GCP

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-hosting

I have this multi layered application entirely hosted on GCP. At the moment, we only have the back-end part. Front-end and API are to be developed. For the front-end, the decision has been made - it will be a React.js app hosted on Firebase Hosting and the authentication method will be Email/password and users will be provisioned manually through the Firebase Hosting UI.

[image]

As we'd like to have a re-usable middle layer (API) we're in a process of making a decision what type of a solution to be used for our middle layer. The main request here is **only logged in users to be able to call the API** endpoints. Eventually, there will be also a native/mobile application which will have to also be able to make authenticated requests to the API.

My question here is, what type of GCP service is advised to pick here? I want it to be light, scalable and price optimized. Preferred programming language would be C# but Node.js would be also acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

**Firebase Functions** would work well for this authentication requirement. With [Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) you can check for the existence of `context.auth.uid` before proceeding with the call.